# Is there any way to make the last path active in react router v6 using Navlink?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, nav

```
 <NavLink
    to="/account/user"
    className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active" : "undefined")}
  >
    User
 </NavLink>
```

So I've been working with react-router v6 and trying to highlight the active link. I've paths like `/account/user` and `/account`. When I'm on path `/account/user`, both account and user nav menu gets the active class. Is there any way to get it only on user menu/ last path?

Comment: This isn't relevant to matching the end of the path, but just FYI the `NavLink` uses an `.active` class by default, and unless you have a literal `.undefined` class in CSS you might have instead meant to use `isActive ? "active" : undefined`.